# Invalid attempt to call when reader is closed in random manner for a portal which is handling multiple request at same Nanosecond

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I'm facing the problem of critical situation

Invalid attempt to call when reader is closed in random manner for a portal which is handling multiple request at same Nanosecond

from last few days while the situation does not occur while testing or debugging the project.

ex:

Connection in web.config is like this

```
<add name="testconnection" connectionString="Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog=testdb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=testUser;Password=testpassword;Max Pool Size=20000;Min Pool Size=5;Pooling=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and code in C# is like this:

```
SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testconnection"].ToString());

    public string Adscategory(string Name)   
    {    
     string temp = string.Empty; 

     if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)     
     {      
      conn.Open();      
     }       
 SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select Id from TestTable where tid='" + Name + "'", conn);    

   try       
   {      
    temp = Convert.ToString(comm.ExecuteScalar());      
   }   

  catch{}
  finally   
  {          
  conn.Close();       
  }       
return temp;   

}
```

Now i hv two problems

1- Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed which occurs on comm.ExecuteScalar() this line when multiple requests made at same time.

2- The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting. which occurs at conn.Open() which also generate at randomly manner.

any help should be appreciable.

Comment: How many threads are simulataneously hitting your Adscategory function?  It would appear that the answer to this is going to be > 1 in which case it's not threadsafe - hence the errors.

Comment: I would suggest to use `using` to ensure that the connection gets always closed immediately even in case of an exception. That means also, don't use the connection as a field variable. Also, use `Parameters` instead of string concatenation to build your sql query, primarily to avoid sql-injection.

Comment: Instead of using one global connection, try creating one in your function (and close it when done) when you need it. Pooling will take care of re using connections if necessary.

Comment: @WillA: more than 100 requests are occurring in one second. So,pls tell me what should be the best solution for it.

Comment: @alfoks: Dear, We have more than 50 functions in same class so is it feasible to create such a no of instances of connection.

Comment: Really nanosecond precision?

Comment: See Alex's answer, that's what I mean. When you close the connection it goes to pool, not destroyed immediately. Pooling mechanism will reuse a connection if available, so you need no worry of opening too much connections.

Answer (score 2):

`SqlParameter` usage and proper exception handling should help in avoiding errors. `using` disposable objects is also highly suggested to prevent leaking.

```
public string Adscategory(string Name)
{
string temp = String.Empty;
using (SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testconnection"].ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();
    // INJECTION ALERT: Use the appropriate SqlParameters
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT Id FROM TestTable WHERE tid=@nameParam", Name), conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameParam", Name);

        try
        {
            temp = comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch(SqlException ex) { /*DB error, react appropriately !*/ }
        // catch(Exception ex) { /*Gotta catch'em all ... don't do this. */ }
    }
    return temp;
}
```